# Text area scroll bar being displayed in IE 8

Tags: html, css, forms, layout, internet-explorer-8

I an using a text-area of fixed size in a form to take input from user.Even though I have made the resize property of the text-area none the scroll bar is still getting displayed as seen in the picture.I don't want the scroll bar getting displayed in the text-area.

The code is working properly in Firefox and chrome though without any errors but in IE it's not..

HTML code...

```
<label for="qual" class="label">Description and Quantification of Impact to the extend possible:</label>
<textarea id="qual" rows="5" cols="50" style="resize:none" placeholder="Description and Qualification"></textarea><br><br>
```

CSS code...

```
   .label 
            { 
                float: left; 
                width:120px;
                padding:10px 30px;
                <!--font-weight:bold;-->
            }
        textarea
            {
                <!--margin-bottom:90px;
                margin-top:50px";-->
                vertical-align:top;       
            }
        .textarea
            {
                resize :none;
                border: none;
                width: 100%;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;   <!-- <=iOS4, <= Android  2.3 */-->
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box; <!-- FF1+ -->
                 box-sizing: border-box; <!-- Chrome, IE8, Opera, Safari 5.1-->
            }
```

The output I'm getting in IE 8..

[image: The output i am getting]

Even though i don't want the unselected scroll bar to appear it's still getting displayed..

I tried putting the code in jsfiddle but it won't open in IE 8 without errors that's why I posted the code and picture here..

Comment: I've found that http://jsbin.com/ works in IE8.

Comment: In jsfiddle.net at least the results are working in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

just put style="overflow-y:hidden" to remove scroll

Answer (score 0):

`resize` has nothing to do with scrollbars. You're looking for `overflow`.

If you want the scrollbar to appear only when the content is long enough to scroll, use `overflow:auto`

If you want to prevent all scrolling, use `overflow:hidden`

Comment: is right. And, You can also be direction specific. Like overflow-x:hidden, overflow-y:hidden for horizontal and vertical scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow: auto;` to `textarea`. 
See http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/eQF22/2/embedded/result/ 
You could also add different properties specifically for horizontal `overflow-x: hidden;` or vertical `overflow-y: scroll;` (making scrollbars always persistent) scrollbars.